# if else-if in sub-function without returning null

Tags: java, if-statement

I have my original code something like this,

```
public String getToken() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  if (a.getMeow() == "2") {
    if (a.getBow() == "3") {
      return a.getBow();
    } else if (a.getBow() == "4") {
      return a.getMeow();
    }
  } else {
    if (b.getBow() == "2") {
      return b.getBow();
    } else if (b.getBow() == "10") {
      return b.getMeow();
    }
  }
  String meow = a.getMeow;
  meow += "2";
  return meow;
}
```

Now, I want to refactor this code, so that the code in the if and else conditions is in sub-functions

```
public String getAString(A a) {
  if (a.getBow() == "3") {
    return a.getBow();
  } else if (a.getBow() == "4") {
    return a.getMeow();
  }
  return null;
}

public String getBString(B b) {
  if (b.getBow() == "2") {
    return b.getBow();
  } else if (b.getBow() == "10") {
    return b.getMeow();
  }
  return null
}

public String getToken() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  if (a.getMeow() == "2") {
    return getAString(a);
  } else {
    return getBString(b);
  }
  String meow = a.getMeow();
  meow += "2";
  return meow;
}
```

But there is a problem in the re-factored code, if none of the conditions in `if (a.getBow() == 3)` after it is inside the condition, then in the original code it would have just skipped these, and returned the meow.
But in this code it will return null.

It seems pretty simple, but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Can you please tag with some language? Without knowing the language the code is impossible to understand.

Comment: Tagged it. It's just a sample code.

Comment: This is wrong: `a.getMeow() == "2"`, you compare references instead of contents. Use `a.getMeow().equals("2")`

Comment: Yes, please don't look at the exact syntax. I am a beginner in Java. Just want to know the if else-if answer

Comment: How about you take both ? It's good to learn proper syntax from the beginning, and it's especially important to take good habits when you're a beginner. Plus you cannot compare strings with `==` in Java, that might be where your problem comes from, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for nulls and return a valid string in case if both are null:

```
public String getToken() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  String res = null;
  if (a.getMeow().equals("2")) {
    res = getAString(a);
  } else {
    res = getBString(b);
  }
  if (res == null) {
    res = a.getMeow();
    res += "2";
  }
  return res;
}
```